# How to draw random samples from a negative binomial distribution in R?

Tags: r, self-study

Let $X$ have the Negative Binomial distribution with parameters $r$ and $p$.  The Negative Binomial distribution is a mixture distribution or compound distribution. That is $X$ is $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is randomly chosen from a $\text{Gamma}(r, p/(1-p))$. Use this relation to write an R function for randomly drawing $n$ Negative Binomial random samples. *Hint*: Use the R functions `rpois` and `rgamma`.

Comment: If this is [tag:homework], please tag it accordingly. Someone will probably help you provided you indicate where you get in trouble.

Comment: If it's indeed a homework Q, you certainly get more fun questions than I do. :)

Comment: As indicated in the OP's the comment to Xi'an's post, I have added the `homework` tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If this is *not* a homework question, you're probably better off with the `rnbinom` function from `stats`. If you're lucky (I haven't checked) you can check it's source to see how the implementers did it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is contained in the description of the mixture decomposition of the negative binomial distribution as a Poisson distribution where the parameter is itself *random* with a Gamma distribution. How much more of a hint do you need?

Comment: yes this is hoemwork. I used rgamma to initially generate a random variable. that random variable i allotted to the value of lamdba and used that for the lambda in rpois. But it doesnt work. Pls tell me where im wrong.

Comment: x <- rgamma(1, shape=2, rate=0.1)
x
lambda <- x
ylim <- c(0:1)
y1 <- rpois(n, lambda)
plot (y1, ylab="probability" ,ylim= ylim, type= 'hist'' )

Comment: @Xi'an: This seems to be more of a comment than an answer. :)

Comment: @probabilityman: your R code simulates one single $\lambda$ and reuses it in $n$ Poisson $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ simulations. This is not what is indicated by the compound representation of the negative binomial random variable, compound of *one* Poisson variable and of *one* Gamma variable.

Comment: rgammapois <- function( n , k , t ) {
    lambdas <- rgamma( n , shape=k , scale=t )
    rpois( n , lambda=lambdas )
}
# y1 and y2 will converge
y1 <- rgammapois(100000,4,2)
y2 <- rnbinom(100000,size=4,mu=4*2) # size = k; mu = k*t
hist(y1,prob=TRUE)
hist(y2,prob=TRUE)

Comment: Im not able to type out with line spaces, but i got a good plot using the above code, please tell me if this is apt. I used a function to generate the above sequence

Comment: I agree we should not be doing other people's homework for them. That was not the intent of my comment. :) I think @whuber's edit clarifies the post a bit. Cheers.

Comment: I requested to tell me if im heading in the right direction, not for the solution itself. I posted the solution myself.