# Generate random variables with negative binomial distribution in R

Tags: r, self-study, random-variable, negative-binomial-distribution

How do I create a function in R in order to generate "n" random variables with a negative binomial distribution?

This is for homework, so rnbinom doesn't help.

Comment: First check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info to learn about our policy with homeworks. What kind of help are you looking for? What have you tried yet? What is unclear for you?

Comment: Sorry - I migrated your earlier question to Stack Overflow without noticing the mistake in the code. You've a good answer here now, but for further help on this site with the principles, please do read our homework policy as @Tim says. Once you know what you want to do, if you need more help on how to do it in R, that's a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. The cdf of the Negative Binomial distribution $\mathrm{Neg}(m,p)$ is available as `pnbinom(x,n,p)`, which means $\mathbb{P}(X\le x;n,p)$. You can alternatively recode it as
   $$\mathbb{P}(X\le x;n,p)=\sum_{i=1}^x {n+i-1 \choose i-1} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$$
2. The distribution can be generated from the pdf $F$ by the inverse pdf method: namely, generate a uniform variate $U$ and, when $U=u$, return $F^-(u)$ as a simulation where $F^-$ denotes the generalised inverse of $F$:
   $$F^-(u)=\max\{k\in\mathbb{N};\ F(k)\le u\}$$
   This means you generate a uniform variate with value $u$ and check when the pdf gets above $u$.

Comment: (+1) But this might be a little much help with homework all at once.

Comment: @Scortchi: thanks. I tried to be as textbook-ish as possible... Which reminds me of the discussion I had earlier today with a colleague about our students not reading textbooks any longer...

Comment: Yes, there's still plenty of thinking needed to code this. (I liked the way you used hidden text recently in answering a homework question on sufficiency.)

Comment: Ah, kind of you to notice it! I was unreasonably proud of myself for this presentation trick!

Comment: Thank you @Xi'ian. Maybe I'm on the wrong way. I coded the functions below in R. 
1) combr
    function(k,r) {
    return(factorial(k+r-1) / (factorial(r) * factorial (k-1)))
    }
2) negbinom
    function(k,r,p){
    return(combr(k,r)*(p^k)*((1-p)^r))
    }

My problem is how to generate random values based on this negbinom. I'm a beginner in R.

Comment: @Scortchi migrated first your question to Stack Overflow for that very reason: if your issue is with R programming, the question should be there, not here.

Comment: @x'ian ...Could you not also get the same answer  from the poisson-gamma definition the negative binomial? just for my curiosity

Comment: @ashokrags: this is another property of the Negative Binomial one can exploit, indeed, as discussed in this earlier [question.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19056/7224)